# An example of outer product in R

Tags: r

I am reading a textbook named "An Introduction to R" and it gives me an example I totally cannot understand.

The examples states that

> As an artificial but cute example, consider the determinants of 2 by 2 matrices [a, b; c, d]
>   where each entry is a non-negative integer in the range 0, 1, . . . , 9, that is a digit.
>   The problem is to find the determinants, ad − bc, of all possible matrices of this form
>   and represent the frequency with which each value occurs as a high density plot. This
>   amounts to finding the probability distribution of the determinant if each digit is chosen
>   independently and uniformly at random.

And it provides code:

```
d <- outer(0:9, 0:9)
fr <- table(outer(d, d, "-"))
plot(as.numeric(names(fr)), fr, type="h",
xlab="Determinant", ylab="Frequency")
```

I only know what the first line is doing but have no idea about what the "-" sign in outer() function and what does table() do in this case. Also, why use name() function in the last plot() function

Comment: Use `str()`, `class()` of every object

Comment: Yes, I really appreciate your help and voted your answers.

Comment: What I don't understand is that why there are so many negative votes on this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I should explain this with a very small example first. Let's suppose we just want to find the distribution of determinant `ad - bc`, where `a, b, c, d` are either 0 or 1.

The first line

```
product <- outer(0:1, 0:1, "*")
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    0    0
#[2,]    0    1
```

computes all possible outcomes of paired product, i.e.,

```
0 * 0 = 0
0 * 1 = 0
1 * 0 = 0
1 * 1 = 1
```

This maps to the possible outcomes of `ad` and `bc` in `ad - bc`.

The second line:

```
minus <- outer(product, product, "-")
    , , 1, 1

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1

, , 1, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1

, , 2, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   -1   -1
[2,]   -1    0
```

computes all possible outcomes of `ad - bc`. Perhaps it is not easy to read as they are a 4D array. Then how about:

```
minus <- as.numeric(minus)
#[1]  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1 -1 -1 -1  0
```

Then it is time to make a contingency table of those possible outcomes:

```
fr <- table(minus)
#-1  0  1 
# 3 10  3
```

Finally, the example code plot this table.

---

## What I would do if I am to solve this problem

You felt difficult to read the result of `outer`, is that every time you apply `outer`, the dimension grows. For example, applying `outer` to two 1D vectors results in a 2D matrix, while further applying `outer` to two 2D matrices results in 4D array.

For easy-to-understand purpose, I would use `as.numeric()` to flatten the result of `outer` every time. I would use this:

```
product <- as.numeric(outer(0:1,0:1,"*"))
#[1] 0 0 0 1

minus <- as.numeric(outer(product, product, "-"))
#[1]  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1 -1 -1 -1  0

plot(table(minus))
```

With your original problem, I do:

```
product <- as.numeric(outer(0:9,0:9,"*"))
minus <- as.numeric(outer(product, product, "-"))
plot(table(minus))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All of your questions can **easily** be answered by the function help pages.

#### 1. d is simply a reproducible matrix to start with.

The `outer(0:9,0:9)` creates a 10x10 matrix test-case.

#### 2. `"-"` is the function to complete in the `outer()`

The default is `*` so the first instance of `outer()` multiples the two vectors of `0:9` whereas the second instance calls for subtraction hence the `-`.

#### 3. `table()`

From the help:

> table uses the cross-classifying factors to build a contingency table of the counts at each combination of factor levels.

#### 4. `names()` gives the character names of the `fr` output

`fr` is a named vector. To plot the values against the names (in this case the determinant) the names must be extracted from the `fr` table and coerced to numeric type.

Answer (score 1):

The first line is doing all possible product combination of the sequence `0:9` (see the help `FUN="*"`). So this is a matrix:

```
d <- outer(0:9, 0:9)
str(d)
 num [1:10, 1:10] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
> tail(d)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [5,]    0    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32    36
 [6,]    0    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40    45
 [7,]    0    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48    54
 [8,]    0    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56    63
 [9,]    0    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64    72
[10,]    0    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72    81
```

The second line is doing the difference of all possible combinations of the previous matrix. The results is like computing  the `ab - bc`. This is a four dimension array

```
dd<- outer(d, d, "-")
str(dd)
 num [1:10, 1:10, 1:10, 1:10] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

The third line computes the frequencies of all possible results. The names are the numbers in string (text) format.

```
fr <- table(outer(d, d, "-"))
str(fr)
 'table' int [1:163(1d)] 19 1 2 2 3 2 4 2 4 41 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
  ..$ : chr [1:163] "-81" "-80" "-79" "-78" ...
```

To plot the results you need the numbers in the x axis and the frequencies in y-axis.

```
plot(as.numeric(names(fr)), fr, type="h",
     xlab="Determinant", ylab="Frequency")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first row, `outer()` is used with default settings which is outer product of two matrix. That's why it is 10x10 matrix. For example, for the first column, it products all values of X with Y's first element. Then for the second column, products all elements of X with Y's second element.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
 [3,]    0    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16    18
 [4,]    0    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24    27
 [5,]    0    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32    36
 [6,]    0    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40    45
 [7,]    0    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48    54
 [8,]    0    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56    63
 [9,]    0    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64    72
[10,]    0    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72    81
```

then `outer(x,y,"-")` will give you following result. It will subtrack y elements from x elements.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0   -1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6   -7   -8    -9
 [2,]    1    0   -1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6   -7    -8
 [3,]    2    1    0   -1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6    -7
 [4,]    3    2    1    0   -1   -2   -3   -4   -5    -6
 [5,]    4    3    2    1    0   -1   -2   -3   -4    -5
 [6,]    5    4    3    2    1    0   -1   -2   -3    -4
 [7,]    6    5    4    3    2    1    0   -1   -2    -3
 [8,]    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0   -1    -2
 [9,]    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0    -1
[10,]    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1     0
```

But remember, we did this outer minus function in vectors. In your example, they are also 10x10 matrixes. So they will produce more than one matrixes. Table is for that.

`names(fr)` makes all table elements a string vector(!)(distinctive), and `as.numeric()` is used to force them to be numeric.